# Api 8: проблемы совместимости

Tags: android

Использую android.support.v4, на девайсе с android 4.0 все работает, но на 2.2 выдает во такую ошибку ... файл apk весит 17 mb

```
 08-18 16:21:43.528: E/logwrapper(176): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: а в коде точно не вызываете `tc` ? и что там на 17 мб может быть? не картинки в мегаразрешении? Может сделать две версии? Пользователи порадуются (если программа нужная).

Comment: картинок так раз много, использую android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, com.google.ads.AdView, android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle, android.support.v4.app.Fragment, android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,  android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat 
по сути просто справочник с кучей  html

Comment: попробуйте убрать часть файлов, что бы уменьшить хотя бы до 2-3 мегабайт. Если после этого все заработает, тогда наверно нужно будет изучить, как сделать [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).